Login with Linkedin - not redirecting back to my app
Context:
I'm developing a "login with LinkedIn" feature on Laravel 11 using socialite. This requires 2 endpoints:

One that redirects the user to a LinkedIn login page
One that LinkedIn redirects to if login was successful

Expected vs. Actual Behavior:

Expected: After logging into LinkedIn, I should be redirected back to my app’s URL.
Actual: After a successful LinkedIn login, I’m stuck on a blank screen with the following URL:
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/login-success?app_id=223222338&auth_type=AC&flow=%7B%22state%22%3A%22nyjguHjmyBKUABGUwXTQdEGNjzI8jZzLofZlWwTk%22%2C%22creationTime%22%3A1734052104859%2C%22appId%22%3A223222338%2C%22authorizationType%22%3A%22OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_CODE%22%2C%22redirectUri%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5173%2Flinkedin%2Fcallback%22%2C%22currentStage%22%3A%22LOGIN_SUCCESS%22%2C%22currentSubStage%22%3A0%2C%22authFlowName%22%3A%22generic-permission-list%22%2C%22scope%22%3A%22openid+profile+email%22%7D

I have checked that my application is configured with the correct redirect url. See my services.php below:
    'linkedin-openid' => [
        'client_id' => env('LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost:5173/linkedin/callback',
    ]

I have also double checked if this same url is configured in my app in my developer account:

And finally, this is my service that creates the url that takes the user to the LinkedIn login page:
class LinkedInAuthLinkService
{
    public function execute(): string
    {
        $state = Str::random(40);
        Cache::put("linkedin_state_{$state}", auth()->id(), now()->addMinutes(60));

        return Socialite::driver(SocialProviders::LINKEDIN)
            ->stateless()
            ->with(['state' => $state])
            ->redirect()
            ->getTargetUrl();
    }
}

I tried to reach out to LinkedIn support but they said I should post this on Stack Overflow.

You need an actual domain, or an exposed IP address. LinkedIn (or any other OAuth provider for that matter) cannot redirect to "localhost".

@IGP it is actually possible, at least it is with LinkedIn. It was working absolutely fine, but for some reason LinkedIn stopped redirecting to my local.

Different tech stack (NodeJS), same issue with localhost. It was not working, then it worked for a few hours with a different account without any changes, now getting blank page for both accounts. LinkedIn's status pages are all green, regular usage of LinkedIn works, this looks like an issue on their end.

Looks like LinkedIn has finally fixed the issue.
